# Pycharm vs Canopy and matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm, canopy

I'm working on the baby names lab that grabs the US census data of baby names from 1880 to 2021 and plots the occurrence of two chosen names on a graph.

Canopy IDE does a great job with the lab:

[Canopy Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apNFf.jpg)

yet PyCharm does not do a great job:

[PyCharm Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lauU.jpg)

One thing:  The matplotlib in Canopy comes with Canopy and it's older than the current matplotlib I'm using in PyCharm. Not sure if that's a big deal.

Can you look at the code and give me a reason why PyCharm is not giving a good graph and what changes I need to make to get a good graph in PyCharm?

```
import os.path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show

name1='Michael'
name2='Michele'

# Get the directory name for data files
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  

#initialize the aggregators
years1=[]
number_of_people1=[]
years2=[]
number_of_people2=[]

# Scan one year's file at a time
for year in range(1880,2021):
    # Open the file
    filename = os.path.join(directory, 'yob'+str(year)+'.txt')
    datafile = open(filename,'r')
    # Go through all the names that year
    for line in datafile:
        name, gender, number = line.split(',')
        # Aggregate based on name1
        if name == name1 and gender == 'M':
            years1 += [year]
            number_of_people1 += [number]    
        #Aggregate based on name2
        if name == name2 and gender == 'F':
            years2 += [year]
            number_of_people2 += [number]        
    #Close that year's file
    datafile.close()
    
# Plot on one set of axes.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.plot(years1,number_of_people1,'#0000FF')
ax.plot(years2,number_of_people2,'#FF00FF')

ax.set_title('U.S. Babies Named Michael(blue) or Michele(pink)')
fig.show()
```

I've tried both IDEs with the listed code and got good results from Canopy but bad results from PyCharm.